# Create mask based on element inside Pandas Series

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with around 250k rows, here's code to create a small version of it;

```
some_dict = {'month end': {0: pd.Timestamp('2020-10-31 00:00:00'),1: pd.Timestamp('2020-10-31 00:00:00')},'end date': {0: pd.Timestamp('2021-02-21 00:00:00'),1: pd.Timestamp('2021-10-20 00:00:00')},'value': {0: 36.15, 1: 40.10}}
df = pd.DataFrame(some_dict)
```

Previously I've used a mask to get the `value` if the column `end date` is between the column `month end + 2 days` and `month end + 3 days`, like so;

```
mask = (df['end date'] > (df['month end'] + pd.Timedelta(2, 'days'))) & (df['end date'] <= (df['month end'] + pd.Timedelta(3, 'days')))
df['test'] = df.loc[mask, 'value']
```

Right now I'm trying to create a mask according to the row below;

```
mask = (df['End Date'].day > (df['month end'] + pd.Timedelta(2, 'days')).day) & (df['End Date'].day <= (df['month end'] + pd.Timedelta(3, 'days')).day) & (df['End Date'] >= (df['month end'] + pd.Timedelta(3, 'days')))
df['Greater than 2 days up to 3 days'] = df.loc[mask, 'value']
```

which should be `True` for the row with value `40.10`, and `False` for the row with value `36.15`. But both `df['End Date'].day` and `(df['month end'] + pd.Timedelta(2, 'days')).day` produces an error that says `'Series' object has no attribute 'day'`. I'm wondering if it's possible to create a mask that uses the object within the `Series` object? In my case I have `pd.Timestamp`, and I would like to use `pd.Timestamp.day`.

The mask above is for one column, if this could work smoothly I'll try to do the same for other columns, such as `Greater than 4 days up to 5 days`, `Greater than 2 weeks up to 3 weeks`, `Greater than 2 months up to 3 months` etc.

**EDIT**: I tried creating extra columns including the `month end` days like so

```
df['month end day'] = df.loc[0, 'month end'].day
```

and then create the mask using `df['month end day']` instead of `df['month end'].day`, but this won't work for the `end date`-column because it doesn't have the same value in each row, and writing

```
df['end date day'] = df.loc[:, 'end date'].day
```

gives the same error `'Series' object has no attribute ´day´`.

Comment: Just use [`dt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.html) (e.g. `df['end date'].dt.day`).

Comment: omg......... i thought i had to use `df.apply` or something but didn't know how, please write this as an answer so i can green-tick, i've been having this problem for hours :'D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like you have to use `.str` to access the [string methods](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.html) in a Series, you also need to use `dt` to access [datetimelike properties](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.html) of the Series values. If accessing a specific `Timestamp` value from a Series, then you don't need to use `dt`, since you're working with `Timestamp` directly.

So, summarizing, just use `df['end date'].dt.day` and you should be fine.